# Meteor: callbacks passed to non-Meteor libraries

Tags: node.js, meteor, middleware

I am using the restivus in meteor and simple:json-routes as a middleware.

Within the middleware function, once the file data is recieved, the insert mehod on the collection fails.

error: `Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.`

```
JsonRoutes.Middleware.use((request, response, next) => {
    if (request.url === "/upload" && request.method === "POST") {
            let fileInfo, data;


            request.on("data", (chunks) => {
                    data += chunks;
                    console.log("data in ");
            });

            request.on("end", () => {

                    res = someCollection.insert({test: 'value'});
                    console.log(res);
                    if (res) next();
            });
    }
    else {
            next();
    }
});
```

Comment: So did you try wrapping the callback with `Meteor.bindEnvironment`? You may need to use a classic function, I can't remember if arrow functions are bindable.

Comment: I wrapped the entire block in bind environment but it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which block? The callback to `request.on('end'`?

Comment: Everything within the JsonRoutes.MIddleware.use block

Comment: I'm not sure the lexical `this` of the `use` callback is the one needed for the `insert` operation... Can you try wrapping up the `request.on('end'` callback instead? (Fairly random shot here)

Comment: yes, you should wrap only callbacks